# DirectX 9 Shader not displaying errors

Tags: c++, shader, directx-9

I'm working on DirectX9 and shaders and I'm using the following code:

```
D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(DirectX::device, "shader.fx", 0, 0, D3DXSHADER_DEBUG, 0, &effect, &errors);

if(errors){
    MessageBox(0, (char*)errors->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
}
```

The problem is, I know there's a error/bug in my shader, but it's not popping out a error box telling what the error is... Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just check the `errors` with a debug break. It'll tell you its content. If you want to know about success, check the return code of `D3DXCreateEffectFromFile`.

Comment: sorry, what do u mean by debug break??

Comment: There is an ability in some IDEs to set breaks on the code when you're in debug mode. It'll stop the program at those breaks so you can determine what's going on. Nevermind, look at my first comment for result checking.

Comment: do `HRESULT hr` `hr = D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(DirectX::device, "shader.fx", 0, 0, D3DXSHADER_DEBUG, 0, &effect, &errors);` and print out hr.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently upgraded to DirectX 11, and this is what I'm doing now.  It should hold up in DX9.

```
char *compileErrors;
unsigned long bufferSize, i;
std::ofstream fout;


//get a pointer to the error message text buffer
compileErrors = (char*)(errorMessage->GetBufferPointer());

//get the length of the message
bufferSize = errorMessage->GetBufferSize();

//open a file to write the error message to
fout.open("shader-error.txt");

//write out the error message
for(i=0; i<bufferSize; i++)
{
    fout << compileErrors[i];
}

//close the file
fout.close();

//release the error message
errorMessage->Release();
errorMessage = nullptr; //or NULL, depending on your compiler

//pop a message up on the screen to notify the user to check the text file for compile errors
MessageBox(hwnd, "Error compiling shader.  Check shader-error.txt for message.", (LPCSTR)shaderFilename, MB_OK);
//shaderFilename and hwnd not defined in this code.  pass as a function parameter or something
```

Also, a `MessageBox` with a first parameter of `NULL` won't show up if you've already deleted the first window you created (for example, a splash window you got rid of once everything finished initializing).  Instead of calling `DestroyWindow` at runtime, just hide the window and release it when the program exits.  Code to hide a window: `ShowWindow(splashWnd, WS_HIDE);`